# Command to convert image.out.dpx to image.jpg

Tags: imagemagick

Currently, i am using Imagemagick tool of latest version. I encoded a 4K image using this tool and got Image.dsc file as output. Now i decoded this image using a software and got output as "Image.out.dpx". Now i want to convert this decoded (out.dpx) file into jpg format. I want commands to convert this using Imagemagick.
Please anyone help me.

Thanks,
Divya. S

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

Please be a little clearer about whether your image is actually of the type I guessed, and also about what actual commands you ran, and if any didn't work, what happened when they failed - including error messages.

Also, please run this command and see if there is any mention of `DPX`:

```
identify -list format

...
...
DNG  DNG       r--   Digital Negative
DOT  DOT       ---   Graphviz
DPX* DPX       rw-   SMPTE 268M-2003 (DPX 2.0)
      Digital Moving Picture Exchange Bitmap, Version 2.0.
      See SMPTE 268M-2003 specification at http://www.smtpe.org           
DXT1* DDS       rw+   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
DXT5* DDS       rw+   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
...
...
```

Note the `rw-` beside `DPX` in my output, meaning that `DPX` files can be both read and written.

**Original Answer**

If your DPX file is this format:

```
Digital Moving Picture Exchange Bitmap, Version 2.0.
See SMPTE 268M-2003 specification at http://www.smtpe.org
```

You can convert from that to JPEG with:

```
magick input.dpx output.jpg
```

---

If your **ImageMagick** is below v7, you will need this instead:

```
convert input.dpx output.jpg
```

Comment: I already used Imagemagick latest version. Here"image.out.dpx" is decoded image.I can't able to convert this using above command. I want to convert this decoded image file into jpg file. If any software tool along with commands is available, please let me know.

Thanks, Divya. S

Comment: i gave command as magick input.out.dpx output.jpg. It is giving error as "magick.exe: improper image header `Image_4K.out.dpx' @ error/dpx.c/ReadDPXImage/
855".

Comment: Please update your question with that information (the info you've just given in these comments). And, from the sound of it, it seems your dpx files are not encoded properly.